# Keeping error details out of responses (Restify)

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'd like to make sure error details are never sent out in responses from my restify-powered API. The best way to achieve that seemed to be via wrapping server.formatters in another function which filtered-out Errors before passing the transformed body on to the relevant formatter. I've probably missed some more obvious way to achieve this, but here's what I came up with. Does this seem reasonable, or is there a simpler solution?

```
const server = restify.createServer()

// wraps all formatters in a function filtering out Error bodies
Object.keys(server.formatters).forEach((name) => {
  const formatter = server.formatters[ name ]

  server.formatters[ name ] = (req, res, body, next) => {
    // keep possibly sensitive details from going out in error messages
    if (body instanceof Error &&
      !(body instanceof errors.HttpError) &&
      !(body instanceof errors.RestError)
    ) {
      body = new errors.InternalServerError('Internal Server Error')
    }

    return formatter(req, res, body, next)
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm a Hapi guy rather than Restify, but take a look at Joi: https://github.com/hapijs/joi